# Hyperlink Function in Formula Field to pass parameter Values

Tags: custom-button, salesforce-id, hyperlink

I'm trying to pass a couple of parameters to the external website through formula field.

Formula Field:

```cpp
IF(
   CONTAINS(
        $Profile.Name, "System Administrator"
   ), 
   HYPERLINK(
        "https://testrackspace.service-now.com/rack_sp?id=sc_cat_item&sys_id=4bb14bc2c84f4e0087fd91e81c4cff48&sysparm_salesrep= Federation_ID__c &sysparm_quotelink= Link__c ",
        "Assign to Product Config"
   ),
   "_blank"
)
```

At the service now end the values are getting populated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right way, you just need to move variables related to the record outside the quotes.

```
IF(
   CONTAINS(
        $Profile.Name, "System Administrator"
   ), 
   HYPERLINK(
        "https://testrackspace.service-now.com/rack_sp?id=sc_cat_item&sys_id=4bb14bc2c84f4e0087fd91e81c4cff48&sysparm_salesrep=" + Federation_ID__c + "&sysparm_quotelink=" + Link__c,
        "Assign to Product Config"
   ),
   "_blank"
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mariia, that worked.